# more efficient way to split string

Tags: java, split, date-parsing, dayofmonth

I've been wondering for a long time. Is there a way to split in-between two keyword identifiers properly without redundant splits? For example we have the text:

```
String text = "ASD WORD-BE HERE YUP";
```

and we want to extract "BE". So we would do two splits.

```
String extractedWord = text.split(" ")[1].split("-")[1];
```

Is there a better way to do this without knowing the exact regular expression? I'm working on a parser for that reads a pdf and I suppose my regex might be a date but there is an unformatted date so I would have to specifically look for "MONTH - MONTH, DAY, YEAR" which is a bit hard to setup for regex. Thanks!

Comment: Have you even *tried* to set up such a regex?

Comment: I tried to put some more relevant tags. Please check.

Comment: If you are *really* concerned about the efficiency, you should not be using `split` and regexes in your parser.  (This question smells of premature optimization ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be regex capture groups. Unfortunately it ends up being more code:

```
var pattern = Pattern.compile("-(.*?)\\s");
var matcher = pattern.matcher("ASD WORD-BE HERE YUP");
var extracted = matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : null;

assert extracted.equals("BE");
```

One potential issue with your code is you always assume the input is valid (which may be fine for your use-case), i.e. you never check the length of the arrays returned by String#split before indexing into them.